# Column to Transacction ID for association rules on dataframes from Pandas Python.

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, arules

I imported a CSV into Python with Pandas and I would like to be able to use one as the columns as a transaction ID in order for me to make association rules.

(link: https://github.com/antonio1695/Python/blob/master/nearBPO/facturas.csv)

I hope someone can help me to:

Use UUID as a transaction ID for me to have a dataframe like the following:

```
UUID     Desc
123ex    Meat,Beer
```

In order for me to get association rules like: {Meat} => {Beer}.

Also, a recommendation on a library to do so in a simple way would be appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Sorry are you after `df.loc[df['UUID'] == some_id', 'Desc']`? Or something like `df.groupby('UUID')['Desc'].apply(list)`?

Comment: Second worked perfectly! However, the type that it gives me back is **pandas.core.series.Series**, is there a way to keep it as a dataframe? If it is editable as any dataframe alike and import as one I guess you just answered my question. So you can post it in answers and I can put you +1 and mark my question as answered. :) @EdChum

Comment: I also thought of something like this:     ``pd.pivot_table(df_du,index=["UUID"], values=["Desc"])``   but it isn't working. @EdChum

Comment: Not sure what your aversion is to `Series` you can use them pretty much the same as a df, you can also just call `reset_index` on the groupby object

Comment: I need it to be dataframe in order for me to export it to R. Still, ``df.reset_index()`` worked excellent. Can you put your comment on answer?

Comment: is there some kind of special format for `R`, are you exporting to csv? you can still do that with a series

Comment: I am exporting to csv, R takes dataframes, and I don't know very well series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate values into a list by doing the following:

```
df.groupby('UUID')['Desc'].apply(list)
```

This will give you what you want, if you want the UUID back as a column you can call `reset_index` on the above:

```
df.groupby('UUID')['Desc'].apply(list).reset_index()
```

Also for a Series you can still export this to a csv same as with a df:

```
df.groupby('UUID')['Desc'].apply(list).to_csv(your_path)
```

You may need to name your index prior to exporting or if you find it easier just `reset_index` to restore the index back as a column and then call `to_csv`